# How to properly type remapped object (useSelectors)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, typescript-typings

Hello Iam trying to create `useSelectors` hook, which should be basically the same as `useSelector`, but it should recieve and object and return an object. So far I got proper typing for all the keys, but values are not being passed properly.

here is my code:

```js
// useSelector.ts
const useSelectors = < U extends {} > (
  selectors: {
    [K in keyof U]: (state: Redux) => TypedUseSelectorHook < Redux > | null
  },
): { [K in keyof U]: TypedUseSelectorHook<Redux> | null } => {
  return reduce(
    selectors,
    (acc, selector, key) => {
      return { ...acc,
        [key]: useSelector(selector)
      };
    }, {},
  );
};

// Component.tsx
const Component = () => {
  const {
    loading,
    hierarchy,
    error
  } = useSelectors({
    loading: selectHierarchyLoading,
    hierarchy: selectHierarchyData,
    error: selectHierarchyError,
  })

  return ...;
}
```

The IDE knows how the types, since it screams at me that I cant assign those types into `TypedUseSelectorHook`, but I dont know how to pass them, any idea? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying I made it work, if someone would be interested in hook that recieves an object of selectors and returns an object of values.

```js
const useSelectors = < SelectorMap extends {} > (
  selectors: {
    [Selector in keyof SelectorMap]: (state: Redux) => SelectorMap[Selector]
  },
): {
  [Selector in keyof SelectorMap]: SelectorMap[Selector]
} => {
  return reduce(
    selectors,
    (acc, selector, key) => {
      return { ...acc,
        [key]: useSelector(selector)
      };
    }, {}
    as {
      [Selector in keyof SelectorMap]: SelectorMap[Selector]
    },
  );
};
```